# Xamarin - Google Maps keep "showing" Malls

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

We are using a stylization with the minimum of items to render (without markers, houses, rivers, etc ...) but somehow we can not disable the rendering of Malls.

The rendering in the browser works perfectly (does not display the malls):

[image: On browser]

But when we load the JSON in the Device the malls keep appearing:

[image: On device]

We using:

Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps v60.1142.1

Code to load style of map on C# code:

```
 public async void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
 {
     map.BuildingsEnabled = false;
     map.SetMaxZoomPreference(18);
     map.MyLocationEnabled = false;
     **map.SetMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.LoadRawResourceStyle(this, Resource.Raw.map));**
 }
```

JSON used to stylize the map:

[Shades of Grey](https://snazzymaps.com/style/38/shades-of-grey)

Is there any additional configuration?

Every help is welcome!

Comment: The map uses layer.  So it looks like JSON is turning on a "layer" that you do not want.  You may want to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to compare request between browser and c# code and compare header to see the differences.  The amount of zoom may have some affect on results.

Comment: @jdweng But the .json style is the same... 
Yes, the zoom affects the view, but only on Mobile. We'd already noticed that, does it make sense?

Comment: I not an expert with all the options of Google Map.  I'm not sure if there is any association between style and map layers.  Read the documentation : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers

Comment: I think you need to delete an Overlay : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays

Comment: Maybe... but the Xamarin DLL does not provide this functionality...

Comment: It does.  I do not know the standard Xamarin overalys.  You may need to create a custom overlay : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/79260/custom-map-tiles-overlay-hides-my-routes-highlight  See if this helps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/maps-api

Comment: The problem with custom overlay is that it is used to insert something custom over the map. Our case does not fit into this scenario ... we do not want to overlay any item on the map, but remove it.

Comment: It looks like if you can access the Overlay you can make style invisible by hiding the Overlay : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-hideshow

Comment: But we do not want to overwrite anything on the map. We just want the map not to render these types of buildings.

Comment: Each map contains Overlays and each Overlay contains styles.  Suppose the road layer has a style that says the layer is blue and you want to change it to green.  Is that overwriting anything on the map?  I'm saying to make the style overlay for building invisible/hidden.